# Is there a structure equivalent to defining a topology on a topology?

Tags: general-topology

I just learned the following definition of a topology:

Given a set $M$, the choice of set $\mathcal{O}$ with elements $\in \mathcal{P}(M)$, satisfying the following conditions:
\begin{align*}
1.)&\  \emptyset\in \mathcal{O} \ and \ M\in \mathcal{O}\\
2.)&\ \text{for any }U,V\in \mathcal{O} \implies U\cap V\in \mathcal{O}\\
3.)& \ \text{any union of the elements of $\mathcal{O}$ is in $\mathcal{O}$}
\end{align*}

is called a topology on $M$. The pair $(M, \mathcal{O})$ is called a topological space.

I'm curious if one could define a topology on a topology-- i.e. a set $\mathcal{T}$ with elements $\in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{M}))$ satisfying the above conditions. Is there a name for the structure $(M, \mathcal{O}, \mathcal{T})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed times when we consider a topology on a topology. Admittedly, we usually phrase things in terms of (collections of) *closed* sets of an existing topological space, but this is inessential: if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and $\sigma$ is a topology on the set of closed sets $\{X\setminus U: U\in\tau\}$, then we can just shift attention to the topology $\sigma'=\{U\in\tau: X\setminus U\in\sigma\}$ on $\tau$, and similarly for classes of particularly nice closed sets (e.g. the compact sets, in a $T_1$ space). Below I'll talk about topologies on sets of closed sets in order to match the literature. (The relevant term is [**hyperspace** or **hypertopology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertopology).)

Probably the simplest example is the **Hausdorff metric**. If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, we get a natural metric on the set of compact subsets of $X$. If $(X,d)$ is compact, this coincides exactly with the set of all closed subsets of $X$. A more complicated example is the **Vietoris topology**.

*As an aside, you may also be interested in the **Gromov-Hausdorff space**. This isn't a topology on a topology, but rather a topology of topolog**ies**: points in the GH space are exactly (isometry classes of) compact metric spaces! This turns out to be a very intricate object. For example, [it has no nontrivial self-isometries](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212364/on-the-global-structure-of-the-gromov-hausdorff-metric-space), so intuitively it "looks different everywhere."*